# this.form.submit() did not work properly with php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a small program of one page and it does not work properly. Hope someone find the scoop in this program.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple test program</title>
</head>
<body>  
<?php
if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
    echo "You county is usa";
}
?>
<form Method="get" action="test.php">
<select name="country" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option value="None">None</option>
<option value="Bidhut">USA</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and I also want to keep USA selected after form submitted.

Answer (score 0):

It is because browser send `login` in params only if you send form by clicking on submit button which has such name. If there are several submit buttons in one form and you click on one of them, then only data from the clicked button will be sent, if you don't click, then it will not be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Do not bind a value to submit button, use the `login` in a hidden field. Also check in select option for the `$_GET` value:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple test program</title>
</head>
<body>  
<?php
if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
    echo "You county is ".$_GET['country'];
}
?>
<form Method="get" action="test.php">
<select name="country" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option value="None"<?php if($_GET['country'] == 'None'){ echo ' SELECTED'; } ?>>None</option>
<option value="Bidhut"<?php if($_GET['country'] == 'Bidhut'){ echo ' SELECTED'; } ?>>USA</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="login" value="login" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for selected with jQuery

```
$("#id-select").val("<?=$_GET['country'];?>");
```

SEO y Posicionamiento Web http://www.skillcorp.com.ve